# #1111 - Invalid use of group function: MAX COUNT doesn't work with MYSQL5.5

Tags: mysql, function, group-by

I have a table `userInteret`, I want to select the max on commun interet between user.
I tried this query:

```
SELECT nomInteretUser,idUser,COUNT(nomInteretUser) FROM `userInteret` 
WHERE nomInteretUser IN('piano','flute','chien') GROUP BY idUser
```

but I want the MAX of this COUNT, when I tried this :

```
SELECT MAX(COUNT(nomInteretUser))FROM userInteret 
WHERE nomInteretUser IN('piano','flute','chien') GROUP BY idUser;
```

It always makes error :

> MySQL a répondu: Documentation
>
> ## 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: Try this query: `SELECT MAX(t.total)
FROM 
(SELECT
  COUNT(nomInteretUser) total
FROM
 userInteret
WHERE
 nomInteretUser IN (
  'piano',
  'flute',
  'chien'
 )
GROUP BY idUser
) t`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT idUser,COUNT(nomInteretUser) counts 
FROM userInteret
WHERE nomInteretUser IN('piano','flute','chien') 
GROUP BY idUser
ORDER BY counts DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks Miahia, Now I wan't to change the structure " IN('piano','flute','chien') " to dynamic array ????

Comment: @user3070123 If you want a dynamic query,ask another question,dont shift the goalpost.It will probably involve some php

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(num) FROM (
    SELECT nomInteretUser,idUser,COUNT(nomInteretUser) as num FROM userInteret WHERE nomInteretUser IN('piano','flute','chien') GROUP BY idUser
) AS MYalias
```

Comment: I have this error : #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Some systems require the inner query to have its own alias. In such case just add "AS {anyname}" at the end of that query. I changed the answer to reflect this.